# Why is SomeFunction.prototype displayed like "SomeFunction {}" in console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let the code be like this:

```js
function Person(){}
console.log(Person.prototype); // Person {}
console.log(Person.prototype instanceof Person); // false
console.log(Person.prototype instanceof Object); // true
```

So why is `Person.prototype` displayed like `Person {}` whereas it is an instance of `Object`?

Comment: @decpk no, this code snippet is valid. The only invalid part is the colon instead of semi-colon.

Comment: `console.log(Person.prototype); // Person {}` doesn't make sense. In which console (browser?) do you see that?

Comment: Stack Overflow console displays `{}`. Firefox displays `Object {}`. Chrome and Edge display `{constructor: ƒ}`. I'm testing on Windows 10.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - node shell

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

[found the relevant part of the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring)

Check the note (emphasis mine) for `Object.prototype.toString()`

> Historically, this function was occasionally used to access the String value of the [[Class]] internal slot that was used in previous editions of this specification as a nominal type tag for various built-in objects. The above definition of toString preserves compatibility for legacy code that uses toString as a test for those specific kinds of built-in objects. **It does not provide a reliable type testing mechanism for other kinds of built-in or program defined objects**. In addition, programs can use @@toStringTag in ways that will invalidate the reliability of such legacy type tests.

---

### Original Answer:

> So why is Person.prototype displayed like "Person {}" whereas it is an instance of Object?

By virtue of the fact that different engines display it differently, it obviously hasn't been written into the ECMAScript spec what the `.toString()` method of a `prototype` should output.

More importantly - what does it matter?

Comment: The matter is what constructor is used ("by engine") for creating "prototype" property of a function. Is it like Person.prototype = new Person() or new Object() or just {}

Comment: @LoneMayson - See the bolded part of the note. Also if you mean you want to find out the `Person` function, then you access `Person.prototype.constructor`, which has a `name` property, but you really shouldn't be relying on that.

Answer (score -2):

It's an object with a constructor function. `Person.prototype.constructor` will be a function.

`prototype` is used for [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in JavaScript. Person can also be used like a class to create an instance.

```js
const somebody = new Person()

console.log(somebody instanceof Person) // true
```

Why is it displayed like Person {}?

To indicate it can also be used as a class.

```js
class Test {}
console.log(Test.prototype) // => Test {} same result.
```

Comment: Sure, added a paragraph to clarify.

Comment: The reason why it's displayed that way is completely arbitrary and left up to the creator of the engine, it's not `To indicate it can also be used as a class`